# Joining two tables with if-statements of what to present

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, webforms

I'm stuck, hoping someone out there can kick me in the right direction.

I have a `ListView` where I've been looping out data from a single db-table, using model binding to do this (Web forms project btw). So far so good. Now I'm in need of checking some values in another table, to modify the look of the objects beeing looped out. Essentially what i want to do is, I have 2 buttons in my `ListView`, if a record in the table i want to join exists, one of the buttons should get the `visible = false` attribute.

So I've been trying to write a LINQ-query to do this, so far without much success.

Example of a query I've written

```
var query2 = from l in myContext.Table1
                             join p in myContext.Table1.Where(p => p.pID == 1)
                             on l.pID equals p.pID
                             where l.UserId == 1
```

This only returns the records that do exists in the table i join, i want all the records in Table1 to be presented - and after that run some kind of if-statement to check if a record in the joined table exists or not, causing a button to either show or not.

Further information, I'm using a `SelectMethod` returning a `IQueryable`.

Also, since using model binding, do i need to declare a new class for this joined object, or is there a simpler way (since this will only be used once on the whole site).

Thanks in advance for any hints or help!

**Update**

Using a `ListView` to loop out my data

**Default.aspx**

```
    <asp:ListView ID="MyListView" runat="server" ItemType="Project.Models.Object" SelectMethod="MyListView_GetData">
        <ItemTemplate>
<!-- HERE i want to either add a button, or don't -->
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
public IQueryable<Project.Models.Object> MyListView_GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                int qs2 = 2;
                var user = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();

                var query = from p in myContext.Object.Where(p => p.pID== qs2)
                            select p;

                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    var doesExist = myContext.Object2.Any(m => m.eID == item.eID);

                    if (doesExist)
                    {
                        // Need to do something here?
                    }
                }

                return query.OrderByDescending(item => item.eID);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Desc.");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you want a button added for each item in your list view? Or just one button for the entire list view?

Comment: I want to add a button for each item- actually, a link-button or a ordinary <a href="....> will also do the trick, since the button i want to add is to be used as a link, containing the "eID". What I'm trying to do is have the button show different texts. If "doesExist" returns true i want one text, if it returns false i want another text. But the link will always be the same, for example (mysite.com/Default2.aspx?eID=3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Any() to check if a record exists. So if you wanted to check if a record exists with UserId of 99 you could do:

```
var doesExist = myContext.Table2.Any(m => m.UserId == 99);
```

That returns a bool. You can easily use that bool to set your button

```
button.Visible = !doesExist;
```

Edit for your comment:

After your done with your first query, go ahead and determine if the record exists, and then switch the button's visibility with the result.

For example if you have some method called DoWork that executes and populates your listbox:

```
void DoWork() {
    ... execute your first query
    ... populate your listbox

    var doesExist = myContext.Table2.Any(m => m.UserId == 99);
    yourButton.Visible = !doesExist;
}
```

I can't really say where exactly you should put this without seeing the rest of your code. But since you mentioned, "i want all the records in Table1 to be presented - and after that run some kind of if-statement to check if a record in the joined table exists or not, causing a button to either show or not", it's clear that it has to happen after your first query.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be the first step towards a solution to my problem! However, I still do not know where and how to do this. Right now I have a method returing a IQueryable<> to my ListView, looping out, say 20 items with a button for each. Where can i place this if-statement, in the code-behind or should i do it directly in the .aspx page?

Comment: Check my edit. It's hard to say without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks again, now I understand! What I did now was to run a foreach-loop, checking for a match every iteration. Now for the final problem, since I use a ListView to present this data (20 posts or so) I can't use the button-control, since I can't manipulate that from my code-behind (random id's). Would you happen to have an idea on how to solve this as well? I'm thinking that perhaps I could add a control for every "<ItemTemplate>" row in my Select-method, or is there a better way (mine perhaps is not even an working option). I'm updating my post with some more relevant code now!

Comment: Yea let me see the other code. I'm not very experienced in web forms but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Figured it out! What i did was create a method in my code-behind, that ran a check of the record existing and then returning the appropriate string. Simple as that, thanks a lot for sending me in the right way. Marking this as the answer!